# OpenBox desktop environment, GTK 4.12 applications, themes create ugly shadows in menus, used CSS to remove some but not all gone

Tags: css, gtk

I have recently switched to the OpenBox desktop environment changing from XFCE.  My GTK 4.12 applications are running well, but I noted that all drop down menus have ugly shadows around them.  I have created some CSS and managed to remove some of the shadows but when you have a menu containing multiple levels of submenus then only the first submenu (from the main menu bar) has the shadows removed and then all subsequent menus have a shadow at the bottom of the menu.  It looks ugly and I'd like to remove it but cannot work out why the CSS that I have created does not work.  The CSS is as follows:

```
popover contents 
{ 
   border: 1px solid black;
   border-radius: 0;
   border-width: 1px;
   box-shadow: none;
};
```

I have looked at the CSS information for GTK 3.x and 4.x and cannot find a way forward.  I have used GTK Inspector and noticed that when I access a submenu that "tooltip" pops up in the CSS nodes section.  I could not work out a way of keeping it on the screen so that I could then look at the CSS nodes and maybe work something out.  Searches for popover and tooltip did not find any results.

Comment: This bug happens in most X window managers. Try installing (picom)[https://github.com/yshui/picom]. It has an option for configuring the shadows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. **Install `picom`**

```bash
sudo apt install picom
```

2. **Start `picom` on boot.** This can be done by many ways depending on the desktop environment. In Openbox add the following line in `~/.config/openbox/autostart`. In other X desktops use the file `~/.xprofile` instead.

```
picom &
```

3. **Configure `picom` to remove shadows.** Even after installing picom some weird shadows could still be visible in `~/.config/picom.conf` add the following lines (or modify them if already existing):

```
shadow = false;

wintypes:
{
  dropdown_menu = { shadow = false; }
  popup_menu = { shadow = false; }
  utility = { shadow = false; }
};
```